Pointwise and total convergence of a real parametric function series.
Exercise
Consider the function series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{e^{\alpha n}+n}x^n.
$$

Discuss the pointwise convergence of the provided series for $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$.
Discuss the total convergence of the provided series for $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$.
Find the biggest set $A$ such that the function $f$ defined as

$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{e^{\alpha n}+n}x^n
$$
is continuous on $A$, as $\alpha$ varies in $\mathbb{R}$.
Solution

For $\alpha\leq0$, a necessary and sufficient condition for the series to be convergent is that $x\in[-1,1[$; if instead $\alpha>0$, we have that

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{e^{\alpha n}+n}|x|^n\sim\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|x|^n}{e^{\alpha n}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \bigg(\frac{|x|}{e^{\alpha }}\bigg)^n, 
$$
which converges if and only if $\frac{|x|}{e^{\alpha }}<1$, hence if and only if $|x|<e^\alpha$. If $|x|\geq e^\alpha$, the series does not converge.

When $\alpha\leq0$, the series is totally convergent on the intervals $[-a,a]$, $0<a<1$; when $\alpha>0$, the series is totally convergent on the intervals $[-a,a]$, $0<a<e^\alpha$.

For $\alpha\leq0$, $A=]-1,1[$;  for $\alpha>0$, $A=]-e^\alpha, e^\alpha[$.


I wanted to know if the solution provided to this exercise is correct, and in case if there are better ways to justify the answers.
